# Using two selectAll on one axis

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I want to use two selects on one axis. Like this:

```
svg.append("g")
    .call(yAxis)
    .selectAll("line").do(something)
    .selectAll("text").do(something);
```

Naturally this won't work, as the second "select" is starting at the "line" element.

Any ideas?

Thank You

Rick

Comment: What are you trying to do? Select all of these elements and then apply the same function to all of them?

Comment: I am trying to select all "line" elements below the "g" and add them some properties. Then I want to do the same with the "text" elements. I was trying to do it in one statement. But as Christopher Hackett pointed out I think it is better to do it in two steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do something along the lines of

```
var x = svg.append("g").call(yAxis);
x.selectAll("line").do(something);
x.selectAll("text").do(something);
```

Of course make sure `x` is named something appropriate for your situation.

Comment: Thank you! Stupid me for not seeing this. I was so hard trying to force it in one statement, that I wasn't able to think out of the box. ;) Thank You!